# Practice Repository for learning J

Tags: j

Are there any sets of practice problems that introduce a variety of J concepts, or just allow for repetitive experience using J? (i.e. codingbat for Java)

I am trying to get into learning J, and I understand most concepts as I read about them, but I find it hard to sit down with a problem and solve it because I haven't had much experience just using even the basics.

Answer (score 1):

The place that I would begin is with the labs. In the jqt environment they are found in the menu `Help|Studio|Labs..` In JHS environment they are found in the `tour|labs`menu. Pick an area of interest and work your way through. If you don't have a particular area of interest, there are some very good introductory labs under the heading of `Core Language`. Labs are great learning tools because they allow you to work in the environment as you are being given information.

Also, the http://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Guides/Getting_Started is a good link to hit as it gives access to the tools that have been created to help you learn J. There are introductory books that are available within the J environment to help you get a sense of the language as you first begin. Also the forums are worth monitoring as even though some of the questions will be beyond a beginner, you will see beginners ask questions and the community is pretty good about bringing people up to speed with the language.

The learning curve with J can be steep and we have all been in the position of beginning.